# PHP getting specific tags from file_get_contents

Tags: php, json, file-get-contents

`$landings = file_get_contents('http://www.domain.co.uk/page.php');`

In the above example URL I want to only select and copy the HTML from a specific element `#sidebar-bgbtm`

From there I would like to export the HTML as a JSON value.

Is there any way of doing that?

Thanks

Comment: Yes; use a DOM parser. PHP's [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/domdocument) and [SimpleHTMLDOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/‎) are two popular options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are familiar with jQuery syntax, PHP Simple HTML DOM might be good place to start
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('http://www.domain.co.uk/page.php');

$result = $html->find('#sidebar-bgbtm', 0)->outertext;
```

And then export to json:

```
echo json_encode( array( 'outertext' => $result) );
```